# How do you say "A story is set in another place"

Tags: translation, grammar

Does anyone have an idea of how to translate "This story is set in a small town". I've been looking around but I haven't found a good way to translate "Set in".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"be set in" = the action takes place there/then

How about this:

這個故事在一個小鎮中發生.

Comment: suggestion:look up setting in nciku( 故事背景，故事场景)

Comment: or 這故事發生在一個小鎮. Sounds more natural to me

Comment: "set in" in required sense can also be found in nciku:  以罗马为背景的小说 a novel set in Rome

Answer (score 6):

1.故事发生在某火车站上。....(伊塔洛·卡尔维诺：如果在冬夜，一个旅人；萧天佑译)

2.话说梁山泊聚义厅上....(施耐庵：水浒传--第五十一回）

Comment: 发生在 will work most of the time, except that, when it is used on fictions, it speaks as if they were facts.

Comment: Like "話說...."  ^_^  It also reminds me that many frictions start with something like "從前有一個小村莊 ...."

Answer (score 3):

这个故事发生在一个小镇`上`。

If you wanna a complete and natural sentence, this is it. `上` kinda finishes the sentence, otherwise it will be considered rather firm and rigid like you emphasize the 'small town' as a location instead of other location.